# ListView with Title

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Is there a way to insert another `View` above the `List` in a `ListView`?  For example, I want a Title Bar (TextView) that sits on top of the `List`, and scrolls out of view as the List scrolls.  I can think of two ways so far of doing this, but both are hacks.

Idea #1 - Use a LinearLayout that pretends to be a ListView.  But the problem is you are unable to take advantage of the "smart" loading/unloading of views that an adapter provides.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>

        <TextView/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" />    # add ListItems here

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Idea #2 - Use a hacky `ArrayAdapter`, with a `getView` method similar to this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(position == 0)
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
    else
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.regular_list_item, null);

    ...

    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simple. Just add a header view to your `ListView`

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Hello. I'm a header view");

listView.addHeaderView(textView);
```

Comment: Make sure to call `setAdapter(null);` before setting the header. Or, add the adapter only after setting the header.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that existed!